# Open camera and Capture image issue

Tags: android, android-camera, android-securityexception

I am trying to make a simple application which uses the system camera application to take picture. I have tested my app in android version 6 and my app opens device's camera successfully. But in some android v6 devices (like Samsung Galaxy A3) I get the following security exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
     at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1621)
     at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1574)
     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity (ActivityManagerNative.java:3182)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1541)
     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4298)
     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult (BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult (FragmentActivity.java:79)
     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4245)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult (FragmentActivity.java:859)
     at iforest.photogps.MainActivity.captureImage (MainActivity.java:203)
     at iforest.photogps.MainActivity.access$000 (MainActivity.java:73)
     at iforest.photogps.MainActivity$1.onClick (MainActivity.java:130)
     at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5721)
     at android.widget.TextView.performClick (TextView.java:10930)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:22620)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7331)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I already add permission checks to my code:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
         && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
         && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //TO do here if permission is granted by user
} else {
    //ask for permission if user didnot given
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
    }
}
```

and later on I call capture image:

```
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    String authorities = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider";
    Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authorities, photoFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);  <-- line 203

}
```

From the logs I see captureImage line 203 with startActivityForResult is called. Since I already ask for permissions of camera why I get SecurityException to open camera in specific device Samsung Galaxy A3 -Android 6? In other devices with same version no error occurs to open camera.

Comment: Use this permision also <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Refer:- http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample and yeah you need to add this permission also <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Are you sure you haven't refused the permission to take photo on the device? Your code seems to be incomplete (//TO do here if permission is granted by user)

Comment: I already have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in androidmanifest file

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make a simple application which uses the system camera application to take picture

There is no single "system camera application". Your code will start whatever camera app the user wants to use, and there will be hundreds of such apps spread across the ~10,000 Android device models and ~2 billion Android devices.

> Since I already ask for permissions of camera why I get SecurityException to open camera in specific device Samsung Galaxy A3 -Android 6?

Replace:

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
```

with:

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Hoho Android permissions design even weirder than I could imagine. Why to include permission flags into `intent`s?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev: You need to grant permission to other apps to use the `Uri` from your `FileProvider`. Now, under the covers, for improved compatibility, those permissions are supposed to be granted automatically for this particular `Intent` action and extra, but it's always possible that Samsung made changes there. In truth, this particular problem usually results in crashes in the camera app, not the app starting the camera app, and so I am skeptical that this will help, but it is worth a try.